# Accessing the ModelState in Javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, modelstate

I'm trying to put a jQuery animated loader on my asp.net mvc 4 application where when a user clicks on the submit button it will overtake the whole screen with a white wash and a please wait. This all works. The part I'm having a problem with is that when there is a validation error on my form, the client side validation kicks in (which I want to preserve) and it trapped behind the jquery loader screen. I'm calling the loader like so:

```
        $(function () {
            $("#submitbtn").click(function () {
                $("#loading").fadeIn();
            });
        });
```

in my `$(document).ready(....` function. My first thought was to use

```
        @if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            <text>$(function () {
                $("#submitbtn").click(function () {
                    $("#loading").fadeIn();
                });
            });</text>
        }
```

but when the page loads this is valid and it will write it out (my bad I should have known). Now I'm at a loss, I'm not sure how to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you need to access the ModelState? You want to show the loader each time the submit button is clicked right? And you have a client-side validation. So why not just show the loader if the client-side validation succeeds, isn't that enough or I misunderstood your scenario?

Comment: @vonv. That's exactly what I need, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a shot at it based on how I understood your problem. So you have:

```
    $(function () {
        $("#submitbtn").click(function () {
            $("#loading").fadeIn();
            if (validFormInputs()) {                   
                yourForm.submit();
            }
            else {
                // hide the laoder again
                $("#loading").fadeOut(); // or .hide or however you want to hide it
            }
        });
    });
```

Now the loader may not show at all if the submit action happens too quickly, since the submit is a post back and not an ajax post. If on the server-side there is an error that was not caught by your client-side validation then you can just return the view again and you do not have to do something special on your javascript. So your method may look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(YourModel input) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return View(input);
    }

    // do something here, redirect or return the view again
}
```

Again, please take note that this code is for a post back action and **NOT** for an ajax post.

**UPDATE:** 
So basically here is the step:

1. Capture the click event of your submit button `$("#submitbtn").click(function ()...`
2. Show your loader `$("#loading").fadeIn();`
3. Do the client side validation `validFormInputs()`
4. If validation fails then hide your loader `$("#loading").fadeOut();`

   4a. Assumes you are using a validation plugin or in any case, you should have shown the error messages
5. If the validation succeeds then you submit the form `yourForm.submit();`
6. If server-side validation fails then you return the view `return View(input);`

Comment: This is exactly the logic that I was looking for. with that said, it didn't work, the loader just sits there with the client side validation messages underneath. Also, instead of `form.submit();` can I have `return true;` (just curious)?

Comment: Which part didn't work? I'll update the answer to show the logic you need to follow.

Comment: ok, so the console shows that the `validFormInputs` is not defined. Is it a function thats built in or do I need to write it?

Comment: You said in your original question "the client side validation kicks in" and so I assumed you already have one in place. Yes, the `validFormInputs` is where you validate your form on the client side.

Comment: oh no, this is the ClientSide Validation that comes with ASP.NET MVC. I'm really not sure on how to check to see if its valid or not. Thats what I was asking :)

Comment: You can check if the form is valid by doing: `$yourForm.validate(); $yourForm.valid();`. Just use that in place of the `validFormInputs` in my sample code.

Comment: ok so the `$('#myForm').valid()` function worked perfectly. Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it :)